# Función que ordene una matriz conforme a otra matriz

Tags: c++, array, ordenamiento

Tengo la siguiente función en la cual utilizo 2 matrices:

```
int paginas_asig[5]={0,0,0,0,0};
int paginas_sus[5]={0,1,2,3,4};
```

`paginas_asig` tendrá valores generados aleatoriamente entre el 0 y 8.

Estoy usando el siguiente algoritmo de ordenación:

```
void ordenar()
{
    int aux=0;
    for(int i=0;i<5;i++)
    {
        for (int j=0;j<5-1;j++)
        {
            if (paginas_asig[j]>paginas_asig[j+1])
            {
                aux=paginas_sus[j];
                paginas_sus[j]=paginas_sus[j+1];
                paginas_sus[j+1]=aux;
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Utilizo esta función para poder obtener los valores de `paginas_sus` conforme al ordenamiento de `paginas_asig`.

Por ejemplo, si `paginas_asig` contiene los siguientes datos:

```
(5,6,1,2,3)
```

El resultado debería ser:

```
(2,3,4,0,1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Una de las formas de realizar lo que deseas es realizar el intercambio no solo en la matriz que estás ordenando, si no también en la matriz en la que quieres que mantenga el mismo orden:

```
/* Intercambiamos los valores de la matriz como de costumbre */
aux = paginas_sus[j];
paginas_sus[j] = paginas_sus[j + 1];
paginas_sus[j + 1] = aux;
/* Para mantener el mismo orden, hacemos lo mismo con la otra */
aux = paginas_asig[j];
paginas_asig[j] = paginas_asig[j + 1];
paginas_asig[j + 1] = aux;
```

Tu código podría quedar como:

```
#include <iostream>

int paginas_asig[5] = { 5, 6, 1, 2, 3 };
int paginas_sus[5] = { 0, 1, 2, 3, 4 };

void ordenar()
{
    int aux = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < 5 - 1; j++) {
            if (paginas_asig[j] > paginas_asig[j + 1]) {
                /* Intercambiamos los valores de la matriz como de costumbre */
                aux = paginas_sus[j];
                paginas_sus[j] = paginas_sus[j + 1];
                paginas_sus[j + 1] = aux;
                /* Para mantener el mismo orden, hacemos lo mismo con la otra */
                aux = paginas_asig[j];
                paginas_asig[j] = paginas_asig[j + 1];
                paginas_asig[j + 1] = aux;
            }
        }
    }
}

int main()
{
    ordenar();
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        std::cout << "Posición " << i << ": " << paginas_sus[i] << std::endl;
    }
}
```

El resultado es:

```
$ g++ -Wall --pedantic -o pruebas /tmp/pruebas.c
$ ./pruebas
Posición 0: 2
Posición 1: 3
Posición 2: 4
Posición 3: 0
Posición 4: 1
```